# collator string comparison

Tags: java, internationalization

I want to know the cases in which using a collator makes sense(let's not be purists for now). The page [Performing Locale-Independent Comparisons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/locale.html) in javadocs provides one such case. I'm curious as to are there more such cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt there are many other cases, but I can imagine a few:

1. Sorting a date or time column in a CSV properly.
2. Sorting case-insensitively.

Basically, a Collator is a more sophisticated Comparator so anywhere you might use a Comparator you could in theory use a Collator. It is more tuned for Strings, and it assumes that the intuitive form (a String) requires some normalization (CollationKey) before comparison. Other than that, it pretty much just has that one use-case.